How to Add Custom Colors to NuxtUI with Tailwind
I'm working on a Nuxt project and trying to add custom colors to NuxtUI components. I’ve managed to make it partially work, but the process feels a bit clunky. I’m looking for a more straightforward approach, if possible, to include custom colors directly in the NuxtUI color palette.
Steps I’ve Taken
Defining my color in tailwind.config.ts :
theme: {
    extend: {
        colors: {
            variantred: {
                50: '#fff0f0',
                100: '#ffdddd',
                200: '#ffc0c0',
                300: '#ff9494',
                400: '#ff5757',
                500: '#ff2323',
                600: '#ff1a1a',
                700: '#d70000',
                800: '#b10303',
                900: '#920a0a',
                950: '#500000',
            },

In nuxt.config.ts :
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    ui: {
        colors: {
            alternativered: 'variantred',
        }
    }

Using the added color to a component :
<template>
  <UButton color="variantred">Red Button</UButton>
</template>

The Issue
When I try to use "alternativered" as the color for UButton, the base color doesn’t apply as expected. However, adding it in nuxt.config.ts allows shades to function correctly—such as on hover, where the button changes color.
Does anyone have experience with this issue or know a better way to integrate custom colors with full functionality in NuxtUI components?
Documentation Insight
I found in NuxtUI documentation on theming that they suggest using safelistColors to include custom colors. However, without applying safelistColors, the configuration I’ve done above only seems to work.
Environment Details:

Nuxt: 3.13.2

NuxtUI: 2.18.7

Tailwind: 3.4.14


Thank you for any insights!

It seems that the recommended best practice, once you've added the color with its shades in tailwind.config.ts, is to add the color value to ui.safelistColors in the nuxt.config.ts. Then, you can apply the color name directly to the component.
In nuxt.config.ts :
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    ui: {
        safelistColors: ['variantred']
    }

In the component file :
<template>
  <UButton color="variantred">Button</UButton>
</template>

